# Java pass object of any class as a parameter

Tags: java

So the idea is...

In C and in other languages you can pass an untyped pointer as a parameter, e.g.:

C

```
foo( void* p1 ) ;
```

pascal

```
function foo(pointer p1 ) : string ;
```

These are untyped and it is on the function to know what to do with them.  I want to do the same thing in java e.g.:

```
class some class{

   String someMethod(Class p1){
      return (String) p1
   }

}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use an Object type, but it doesn't look like a good design.

Comment: I think you could pass an Object and the cast it to whatever ... but why would you need this im interested

Comment: So the idea is to make a universal way to load a class using reflection and to be able to pass any parameter of any type to the method without using some monster framework like spring.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, post a new question instead of editing your existing question. (If you're looking for opinions, though, Stack Overflow probably isn't the place to ask.)

Comment: Hey there user235....  Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Object`, not `Class`.

```
public String someMethod(Object p1) {
    return whatever;
}
```

Comment: may i ask when would one face such a scenario ?

Comment: @vlatkozelka: If you're implementing the `equals` method, for example.

Comment: This is the answer to the OP's question, but including a mention of Generics (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics ) might also be helpful.

Comment: @vlatkozelka I've recently implemented methods where I wanted the parameter list to be a variable-length list of either `String`, `Pattern`, or some other object that implemented another class of mine.  So `Object...` was the natural choice.  Using `Object` as a parameter may be a sign of poor design, but not always.  That's how `println` is defined.

Comment: So using object ( I have not been doing java that long ) was the correct solution.  Thanks Mucho!

Comment: @ajb wasn't saying it's poor design , i was just interested as of when it might come in handy , and your explanation was good enough , thanks

Comment: @vlatkozelka OK, sorry for misunderstanding.